# How can I tell Exchange 2007 HT which IP address to send mail on?

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007

I have one E2007 server that has HT, CA, MB roles and an old Ex2003 server that is still being used that I am not ready to turn off just yet.

The Ex2007 has two NIC's the first one is for internal and the second one is external. Presently I can send and receive email from Ex2007 but it is sending email using our general purpose internet connection rather than the second NICs public facing external address.

In Ex2003 you could bind SMTP outgoing to a particular NIC. I am failing in finding the same thing on Ex2007. So how do you bind SMTP (out/internet) to a particular NIC on the server?

Thanks,

Norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one internal subnet, you can make sure only the public NIC has a default gateway. If you have additional internal subnets, you will need to do a route statement with the -p switch.